# Error on line 34, column 2 of pubspec.yaml: Expected a key while parsing a block mapping. ╷

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
 dio: ^4.0.0
 flutter_polyline_points: ^0.2.6
 google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.2
```

[nearby_interpreters] dart pub get --no-example
Error on line 33, column 2 of pubspec.yaml: Expected a key while parsing a block mapping.
╷
33 │  dio: ^4.0.0
│  ^
╵
exit code 65

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space before `dio` is only 1, it should be 2 spaces to be consistent to the previous `flutter` line.

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  dio: ^4.0.0
  flutter_polyline_points: ^0.2.6
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.2
```